# Не получается передать список словарей как аргумент функции из одной в другую

Tags: python, парсер, функции, аргументы

Не получается достать список словарей **dicts** из функции **get_content** для функции **save_parsed_date** как аргумент, пытался через **global** но ничего не получилось. Подскажите, пожалуйста куда копать, вот код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import os

URL = "https://www.youtube.com/user/tkhirianov/videos"  # URL = input()

HEADERS = {
    "user agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) "
                  "Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36",
    "accept": "*/*"}

HOST = 'https://www.youtube.com'
FILE = 'dicts.csv'


def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
    return r


def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    dicts = []
    # name_chnl = soup.find('title').get_text()
    video_box = soup.find_all('h3', attrs={'class': "yt-lockup-title"})
    for iterator_find in video_box:
        for items in iterator_find.find_all('a'):
            dicts.append(
                {

                    'title': items.attrs['title'],
                    'href': HOST + items.attrs['href'],

                }
            )

    # print(dicts)


def save_parsed_date(dicts, path):
    with open(path, 'w', newline='') as file:
        w = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
        w.writerow(['Название видео', 'Ссылка на видео'])
        for i in dicts:
            w.writerow((i['title'], i['href']))


def parse():
    html = get_html(URL)
    dicts = []
    if html.status_code == 200:
        get_content(html.text)
        save_parsed_date(dicts, FILE)
        os.startfile(FILE)
    else:
        print('\033[31m ERROR status_code = {}'.format(html.status_code))


parse()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    dicts = []
    # name_chnl = soup.find('title').get_text()
    video_box = soup.find_all('h3', attrs={'class': "yt-lockup-title"})
    for iterator_find in video_box:
        for items in iterator_find.find_all('a'):
            dicts.append(
                {

                    'title': items.attrs['title'],
                    'href': HOST + items.attrs['href'],

                }
            )
    return dicts
```

и

```
dicts = get_content(html.text)
```